# Essential singularity of $h = f \cdot g$.

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, singularity

I want to proof the following claim

> Let $a \in \mathbb{C}$. Consider a function $f$, where $f$ is
> holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{a\}$ and $a$ being an essential
> singularity of $f$. Moreover let $g$ be an entire function such that
> $g(a) \neq 0$. Then $h = f\cdot g$ has an essential singuarity at $z = a$.

**My attempt:**

$f$ has an essential singularity if $\lim_{z \to a} |(z-a)^k\cdot f(z)| = +\infty$ does not exist for every $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Otherwise we would have a pole of order $k$, if $k$ is the smallest number such that the limit exists.

Then
\begin{align}
\lim_{z \to a} |(z-a)^k \cdot h(z)| &= \lim_{z \to a} |(z-a)^k \cdot f(z) \cdot g(z)|\\ & = \lim_{z \to a} |(z-a)^k \cdot f(z)| \cdot \lim_{z \to a} |g(z)| \\ &= \underbrace{\lim_{z \to a} |(z-a)^k \cdot f(z)|}_{\infty} \cdot \underbrace{|g(a)|}_{\neq 0} \\ &= +\infty
\end{align}
for every $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Hence, $h$ has to have an essential singularity at $z = a$.

I am unsure about whether that is enough to proof the claim or not. Can someone confirm my attempt or give a hint how the statement can be proven?

**Edit:**

I am particulary unsure about the second step where I write

\begin{align}
\lim_{z \to a} |(z-a)^k \cdot f(z) \cdot g(z)| = \lim_{z \to a} |(z-a)^k \cdot f(z)| \cdot \lim_{z \to a} |g(z)|.
\end{align}
Am I allowed to do this here?

Comment: Looks fine to me!

Comment: Entirely alternative approach: A meromorphic function has an essential singularity at $a$ iff its Laurent series at $a$ has infinitely many (non-zero) negative-degree terms. Multiplying by a function with a degree-zero term and no negative-degree terms can't change this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is fine because $\lim_{z \to a} |g(z)| = |g(a)| \ne 0$. It might be simpler to argue in the opposite direction. If $h$ has a non-essential singularity at $z=a$ then
$$
c = \lim_{z \to a} (z-a)^k \cdot h(z)
$$
exists for some non-negative integer $k$. It follows that
$$
(z-a)^k \cdot f(z) = \frac{(z-a)^k \cdot h(z)}{g(z)} \to \frac{c}{g(a)}
$$
for $z \to a$, so that $f$ has a non-essential singularity at $z=a$, contrary to the assumption.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution seems fine.

The step
$$\lim_{z\to L}f(z)g(z)=\lim_{z\to L}f(z)\lim_{z\to L}g(z)$$
is viable whenever the right hand side leads you to a determinable expression, which is the case here.